# How to check for number of folders that start with the same word

Tags: c#, winforms, file, directory

I am trying to create a windows form application with a button, where if you click it, it would to be able to search in a folder (I will specify the directory in the program's code - for the sake of this example the directory will be called "C:\#" -) for the number of text files that starts with a text of our choice (again specified in the program's code - for the sake of this example the file will be starting with "HelloWorld" -).

Does anyone know how to achieve a piece of coding that can count the number of files in a specified directory that starts with the characters of our choice.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: could you add a code sample?

Comment: If you provide your current attempt you'll get a quicker answer. As it is now...we should write program from zero and it's useless when there is an existing one to fix. See also [help].

Comment: I think the next time, you should not lose time in writing your assignment, just put a link to it.

Comment: [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) itself contains half an example of how to do this... what have you tried/researched?

Comment: A small tip (I know it'll go ignored): **to write a program is not to Google code snippets** (as it's not to ask for ready code here on Stack Overflow). Sit down, think about it and let's try to write it with tools you have (C# and BCL, their doc is pretty good). What's the point of _" I found through google is to create a text file"_ if you have to SEARCH for files? When you need to buy shoes do you search yellow pages for car shops???

Comment: +1 The question is very clear and explained but pseudo experts want (and have) to see code. One of them downvote and the rest run eager to do the same thing.

Comment: @Elio.Batista why you're so...mean? 7 _pseudo-experts_ downvoted this questions (and yes I'm one of them). Why? Because it dumps a requirement. It's not bad in general, it just against Stack Overflow guidelines (see [help] in case you wish to have more details about this). Of course rules may change but it's what we have NOW. You may disagree but to be _wrong_ (sorry I can't find a better word) isnt who downvoted this.

Comment: Second point: to write `Directory.GetFiles(path, "HelloWorld*.txt").Length` isn't a big programming problem (even for an absolute beginner) then, absolutely yes **I highly appreciate** OP posts his code because I strongly think to help someone you do not need to think instead of him. Anyway this isn't topic for SO comments, usually meta is a better place.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, I have seen mediocre questions upvoted a ton. This is genuine question from a beginner struggling and frustrated with his code.

Comment: @Elio.Batista more _mediocre_ than `Directory.GetFiles(path, "HelloWorld*.txt").Length`? (BTW I don't see why answers are longer than this) Anyway an upvoted _mediocre_ question won't make _this_ question better. Of course IMO. _"...This is genuine question from a beginner..."_. I completely agree but as I said in a previous comment I think Stack Overflow shouldn't replace docs (at least for very basic stuffs).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The problem is there are many approach to accomplish this, I bet he/she was confused on what is the best option, just my thought...

Comment: @Elio.Batista I agree he/she was confused, it seems just SO isn't right place for such _general_ guidance. It doesn't mean such questions are bad _per se_ or they _must_ not be asked (somewhere). It's simply SO tendency nowadays (IMO). Anyway he finally found his answer...

Comment: @user4423819 ;) we're not fighting, it's a pretty common topic here on SO with endless (and often meaningless) debates but you're right: comments aren't right place for this (flagging comments to be removed).

Answer (score 1):

1) Use [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with your path as input parameter. This will return all filenames in that folder as stringarray.

2) Iterate over the array to count how many filenames match your restrictions (i.e. start with HelloWorld and end with .txt)

3) Generate the new Textfile (like you pointed out in the comments System.IO.StreamWriter can be used for this)

If you are having problems with any of the steps above, please be more specific on where you are stuck. I am assuming that you had problems reading the filenames from a given folder.

Comment: Don't worry about it...I've upvoted you! At least you've put me in the right direction of search which what I was looking for! I'm an aerospace engineer but very new to programming and can't understand why some of the members are so negative!

Comment: Just try to tackle one problem at a time. People are glad to help you out with specific problems, if you actually tried it yourself and get stuck. However your question seemed a bit like you are asking to write the code from scratch for you since you did not provide any code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Well I'm trying to create an extension to an engineering software and I was stuck on that particular part of my logical process and couldn't find any functions to use to achieve the program's purpose.

Comment: @HW, many pseudo experts come here looking for fame and not for a willing to help, that is why the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Your question shows no effort of researching for a solution, but I will show you how relaying on your directory example:

```
string directory = "C:/#";
int count = 0;
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.txt");
for(int i=0; i<files.Length; i++)
{
    if(files[i].StartsWith("HelloWorld"))
    {
        count++;
    }
}
MessageBox.Show("Num. of files: " + count);
```

It's not tested and I just wrote it. Tell me if it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for anyone who might have been struggling like me:

```
        try
        {
            if (FilePath == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Browse for and select a file");
            }

            else
            {
                if (activedrawing == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No Drawing Found");
                }

                else
                {
                    string fileName = "InsertImage"+ FileName + ".PNG";
                    string sourcePath = FilePath;
                    string targetPath = info.ModelPath;
                    string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath);
                    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
                    {
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
                    }
                    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```